# Two consecutive wrapfigure images

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

How can I display two consecutive images on the right of the page, with the second appearing below the first? At present the first does not float at all, only the second does. I do not want to place both images in the same wrapfigure, as there could be a page break between them.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty} \begin{document}\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{12em}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{12em}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Image example]

Answer (score 4):

You could put both images into one `wrapfig`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{12em}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
  \smallskip\par
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Otherwise you are limited to one `wrapfig` per paragraph.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty} 

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{12em}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{12em}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: alternate solution]

Comment: I do not want to place both images in the same wrapfigure, as there could be a page break between them if they are near the end of the page.

Comment: If you place a wrapfig too close to the end of the page to fit, it will not start until the next paragraph anyway.  If you put a wrapfig in the middle of a paragraph, it will wait until the next paragraph to start.